# How to launch a document from Wix installation source?

Tags: wix, installation

I had the code to launch the document from where the Word document was installed to, but if there was an update to this document, the entire build would have to be built again just to accommodate this one file.

What I want it to do is to launch the document from the DVD image (or from where ever the EXE Bootstrapper is run from).  How can I find out the source location?

I have tried `SOURCEDIR`, `CURRENTDIRECTORY`, `SourceDir` and nothing seems to work.  Here is the original code that was used to launch the document from where it was installed:

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#auxiliary.aad.file]" />
```

Where this was:

```
<Component Directory="INSTALLDIR" Id="auxiliary.aad" Guid="*" Win64="no">
  <File Id="auxiliary.aad.file" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)\Docs\Release_Notes.docx" />
</Component>
```

So what I did was I commented out the component (so it wouldn't be installed since the DVD image (or wherever I copied the DVD image to) will have the latest release notes and then tried to change the property ID.

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[SOURCEDIR]\Release_Notes.docx" />
```

This isn't the latest of what I have tried.  I have tried `$(var.SOURCEDIR)`, `$(var.CURRENTDIRECTORY)` and many other things, but nothing is working.

Comment: You might need SourceDir, and the names are case-sensitive https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371857(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also, if you're going to reference the SourceDir property, you need to schedule the standard action "ResolveSource" in order to populate the SourceDir property. Beware! The ResolveSource action likely shouldn't execute during a modify/repair/uninstall or else you'll see problems like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155477/uninstall-error-if-original-install-dvd-is-not-in-drive